# Django/Python - overwrite initial loaded values

Tags: django, django-views

I'm quiet new to Django, and I've been struggling with the following:

I have a view that initially has set1=0(False) and set2=1(True). A user can swap this,so to set set1=1(True) and set2=0(False). The user can do this by pushing the 'Update' button. My problem is, that it does change in the backend, but the frontend/view/html is not updated. And I have no idea why..

I created a small example, which, if this works, I'll also get my Django case working..

I have the following:

**views.py**

*So first this view is used, and the initial values for set1 and set2 are set:*

```
class MainSettingsView(generic.TemplateView):
    extra_context = {"main_page": "active"}

    context_object_name = 'main'
    template_name = 'index.html'

    set1 = int(model.set1 == True)
    set2 = int(model.set2 == True)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        model = Setting12.objects.get(pk=1)

        context['set1'] = int(model.set1 == True)
        context['set2'] = int(model.set2 == True)
        return context
```

*And then, based on the chosen option in the radio buttons, it changes the model/db and therefore also the set1 and set2:*

```
class UpdateButton(generic.TemplateView):
        extra_context = {"main_page": "active"}
        context_object_name = 'setting12'
        template_name = 'index.html'
    
        def post(self, request, queryset=None, *args, **kwargs):
    
            if update_type == "set1":

                model = Setting12.objects.get(pk=1)
                model.set1 = True
                model.set2 = False
    
                return redirect(reverse("main"))
    
            elif update_type == "set2":

                model = Setting12.objects.get(pk=1)
                model.set1 = False
                model.set2 = True
    
                return redirect(reverse("main"))
```

*For context, this is what I use in the html:*

**index.html**

```
<form class="card" action="{% url 'setting12' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}

        <h3 class="card-title">Update Settings</h3>


        <input type="radio" name="update_type" value="set1" {% if view.set1 %}checked {%endif%}>    set1
        {% if view.set1 is 1 %} ( Current setting ) {% else %} {% endif %}</input>

        <input type="radio" name="update_type" value="set2" {% if view.set2 %}checked {%endif%}>      Set2
        {% if view.set2 is 1 %} ( Current setting ) {% else %} {% endif %}</input>

        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Update</button>

</form>
```

I do see that the db is changed, set1 and set2 are changed in value when the button is pushed. But I also see is that when it goes from MainSettingsView > UpdateButton > MainSettingsView  that the model is not re-read.. it doesn't go over the model again. So I do think that that is the problem of not getting a updated view. But I can't find a way to do it...

Can someone help me? It's taking me days so far :s

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it =D!!

By removing the `view.` part in my `index.html`, and removing
`set1 = int(model.set1 == True)`
`set2 = int(model.set2 == True)` I removed the whole initial setting that I couldn't overwrite anymore. After that it totally worked :)